# android Glide resource is ready but image not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

use glide to load image on a recyclerview imageview item. impelemented glide listeners i realized that image resource is ready, but image not showing in imageview. when i add imageview.setDrawable(resource) inside glide listener onResourceRady ,then image shows up but in normal not showing here is my code i appreciate any help.

```
GlideApp
        .with(this.myContext)
        .load(item.add)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                e: GlideException?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                myContext.toast("error:\n ${e?.causes}")
                return true
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Drawable?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                myContext.toast("resource ready")
```

//                    holder.img.setImageDrawable(resource)
return true
}
})
.error(R.drawable.neterror)
.into(holder.img)
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glide depends on the returned boolean from the `onResourceReady` method of `RequestListener`, if the returned value is `true` (which is your case) it means that the listener has handled setting the resource on the target. To allow Glide's request to update the target return `false`.
For more information checkout the docs: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html#requestlistener-and-custom-logs